# Filter processes by state in htop

Tags: htop

Is there a way to filter processes in `htop` by their state — e.g., only show running processes (state `R`)?

Answer (score 1):

No, it only filters by process name.

The closest you can get is sorting the columns by state.

Comment: Yes — unfortunately, I already want to sort by the run time (and when I do, the top 100 processes or so all all either sleeping or suspended...)

Comment: Dang! I've heard nice things about atop, never tested it tho'.